# Remove directories interactively using xargs

Tags: xargs

Finding all directories with Gigabyte space usage. Extracting the directory name from xargs and then again xargs to remove them.

```
du -d2 -h ~/Downloads/ | grep -E '[0-9]G' | xargs -I{} sh -c "echo {} | cut -d' ' -f2"  | xargs rm -ri
```

I would like to interactively remove the directory, but I dont get a chance from the bash to enter my option.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot answer interactively to `rm -ri` questions with the last piped `xargs` command: explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18302893/7350091).

Instead, you can put the list of big directories as arguments to `rm -ri`:

```
rm -ri $(du -d2 -h ~/Downloads/* | grep -E '[0-9]G' | xargs -I{} sh -c "echo {} | cut -d' ' -f2")
```

Note that you can replace the `xargs cut` with `awk` as such:

```
rm -ri $(du -d2 -h ~/Downloads/* | grep -E '[0-9]G' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Or even shorter:

```
rm -ri $(du -d2 -h ~/Downloads/* | awk '$1 ~ /G$/ {print $2}')
```

Also note that the above commands won't work well if there are spaces in the filenames.

Comment: The only issue with this is that `{ print $2 }` will print a partial path if the pathname contain spaces.

Comment: You are right, thx. In fact, the whole `rm -ri $()` won't work if the pathnames have spaces. And in fact, the original command in the question wouldn't work either due to the `cut` command. Updating answer.

Comment: @Gohu thanks for the alternative solution. I have found the right one and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is indeed a method to delete directories interactively using xargs. After reading the man pages, I myself came out with a solution.

The -p option along with -n 1 option solves the problem.

```
du -d2 -h ~/Downloads/* | grep -E '[0-9]G' | xargs -I{} sh -c "echo {} | cut -d' ' -f2"  | xargs -p -n1 rm -r
```